# Deployment of XQuery code in MarkLogic on Rocky Linux in WSL results in '500 Internal Server Error with 'CMA-INVALIDPROPERTIES' error

Tags: gradle, windows-subsystem-for-linux, marklogic-10

I'm currently trying to deploy XQuery code in MarkLogic on a Rocky Linux distribution running in Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL). I'm encountering an issue while deploying the code using the following Gradle command:

```
./gradlew -debug -b  deploy.gradle deploy -PmlHost="localhost" -PdeployTestModule="false" -PreplicasCount=0 -PhostsInCluster=1 -PforestsPerHost=1
```

However, I'm getting the following exceptions:

```
Error occurred while sending POST request to /manage/v3; logging request body to assist with debugging: {
  "config" : [ {
    "forest" : [  {
      "forest-name" : "Meters",
      "database" : "Meters",
      "host" : "localhost",
      "enabled" : true
    }, {
      "forest-name" : "Modules",
      "database" : "Modules",
      "host" : "localhost",
      "enabled" : true
    }, {
      "forest-name" : "d11",
      "database" : "d1",
      "data-directory" : "/srv/MarkLogic/d1",
      "host" : "localhost",
      "enabled" : true
    }, {
      "forest-name" : "d22",
      "database" : "d1",
      "data-directory" : "/srv/MarkLogic/d1",
      "host" : "localhost",
      "enabled" : true
    }, {
      "forest-name" : "d33",
      "database" : "d1",
      "data-directory" : "/srv/MarkLogic/d1",
      "host" : "localhost",
      "enabled" : true
    }, {
      "forest-name" : "Schemas",
      "database" : "Schemas",
      "host" : "localhost",
      "enabled" : true
    }, {
      "forest-name" : "Security",
      "database" : "Security",
      "host" : "localhost",
      "enabled" : true
    } ]
  } ]
}

> Task :mlDeployApp FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':mlDeployApp'.
> 500 Internal Server Error: [{"errorResponse":{"statusCode":"500", "status":"Internal Server Error", "messageCode":"CMA-INVALIDPROPERTIES", "message":"CMA-INVALIDPROPERTIES (err:FOER0000): MANAGE-INVALIDPAYLOADerr:FOER00001.0-mlP... (10381 bytes)]
```

Could someone provide guidance on what might be causing this error and how to resolve it?